# Do I need to place a comma before an address?

Tags: punctuation, writing, commas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should the comma be placed in the salutation of a letter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/where-should-the-comma-be-placed-in-the-salutation-of-a-letter)

I am not sure if the way I have formulated the title of my question is correct, so if you know better, please, edit it.

The question is simple: Whenever I thank anyone for his or her answer or comments I usually write (*eg*) "Thank You, George, for Your answer", or "Thank You, Silverglass, for telling me that". Usually in such phrases I place commas on either side of the address, but I don't know if it's correct in English or not.

What about greetings in the very beginning of an e-mail? I do place commas there before the address:

> Hi, Mark,
>
> How have you been? It's been...

or

> Hello, Peggy!
>
> Do you know of any...

but I have seen many times that commas before the address were omitted ("Hello Mark," or "Hello Peggy!"). So, which way is correct?