# Should there be a capital letter after Hello?

Tags: capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I capitalize the starting sentence after a greeting that ends in a comma (e.g. “Hello,”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11906/should-i-capitalize-the-starting-sentence-after-a-greeting-that-ends-in-a-comma)

I have received this email from my hosting provider. And I think the "we" should be with a capital letter (after Hello, ). Am I wrong?

Hello,

we acknowledge receipt of Your request that will be processed in the shortest possible time. This report is for information only;
please do not respond. If you are a registered customer, please
contact us by the accredited requirement from the customer center
******* - https://********.com/ Loging into Your account under which the request relates, you will speed up a resolution of all Your
requests, that require your authorization.

Best regards

Your customer support team

Comment: I'm curious: did the original capitalize "Your" in the middle of the sentence as well, as has been done here (3x)?  (Also, "Loging" is a misspelling, too ~ yours or theirs?)

Comment: Theirs, I just copy and paste. They are not from an English speaking country.

Comment: Interesting.  I'd say this has many more problems besides the lower-case 'w' that you correctly point to (e.g., there'd normally be a comma after "Best regards" as well).  I sure hope those folks are better at troubleshooting than they are at writing prose. :^)

Comment: @J.R. In Italian the **formal** 2nd person plural "Voi", the 3rd person singular "Lei", and the 3rd person plural "Loro" when used, will start with a capital letter, this rule also applies to the corresponding possessive adjectives.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Interesting. I'd regard that as an important piece of the puzzle. Thanks.