# Where to find an authoritative, official and old Reference to the Convention of Capitalization after a Letter Salutation?

Tags: capitalization

Where does the convention to capitalize the body of a letter after the salutation come from and are there any references on the subject giving definitive evidence proving this?

Answers should have a resource that explicitly states that following a salutation with a captial is a rule in English.

The definition of the body starting after the comma in a new paragraph being a new sentence is an exception to this rule. I would like to know where this is defined, preferably with an example from a linguistic book that is widely accepted as a reference.

Another thread I checked and didn't find a reference in can be found [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11906/should-i-capitalize-the-starting-sentence-after-a-greeting-that-ends-in-a-comma).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should one capitalise the first word in the body of a letter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280100/should-one-capitalise-the-first-word-in-the-body-of-a-letter) (@livresque's answer contains 4 references. CMoS may address this, but I haven't found where.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141886/discussion-on-question-by-michacassola-where-to-find-an-authoritative-official).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[An article by Maria Popover, in The Marginalian](https://www.themarginalian.org/2012/12/21/how-to-write-letters-1876/), contains (reformatted slightly):

> I was utterly delighted to discover a rare and remarkable little book
> titled
>
> *How To Write Letters* (UK; public library; public domain) –
>
> a “*manual of correspondence, showing the correct structure,
> composition, punctuation, formalities, and uses of the various kinds
> of Letters, Notes and Cards*”, written in 1876 by **J. Willis
> Westlake** – an English Literature professor at the State Normal
> School in Millersville, Pennsylvania.
>
> From how to address the recipient and sign your name to the
> conventions of business vs. social vs. personal letters to the most
> elegant way to fold the sheet, Westlake presents a guide not only to
> the craft of writing letters, but also to the conceptual elements of
> composition and the role of letters as social currency.

The example below shows that the capital-after-comma-after-salutation convention was in use, and recommended, as early as 1876:

[image]

Westlake even uses this convention in concluding strings, as say in:

*Yours faithfully,*

*The men of the SS Punctuata.*

The double hyphen has sadly bitten the dust. And big Brother could well be eschewed nowadays.

Comment: Thank you very much for your research and result! I just wished it was an English reference and not an American one. But it is interesting that back then Americans also used a comma instead of a colon. Thanks again!

Comment: If we take the publication as being representative, they also used the comma + over-em-dash with  no spaces, and no new paragraph indentation, in business letters.

Comment: Yeah, I remember someone telling me that back than the pieces of paper being written on were a lot smaller, so it might have been done to save paper space?
The script looks too perfect to have been handwritten. Also, I wonder how they would have measured the distance from the right to start the body to have that perfect alignment.