# How to use commas in greetings

Tags: punctuation, commas, greetings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should the comma be placed in the salutation of a letter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/where-should-the-comma-be-placed-in-the-salutation-of-a-letter)

I've noticed that most of Americans I interact with online have a tendency to begin their emails like this:

> Hi Fabio**,**

Meanwhile in my native language we write:

> Hi**,** Fabio

which is taught to us in school.

What's the deal?