# Should the beginner's program read "Hello, World"?

Tags: commas, programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should the comma be placed in the salutation of a letter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/where-should-the-comma-be-placed-in-the-salutation-of-a-letter)

I was thinking today about comma usage and the typical first output for a beginning programmer. In the typical example you see "Hello World" but does proper sentence construction/comma usage rules dictate there be a comma between the greeting and the thing being greeted.

I.e. should a proper sentence read "Hello, World"?

Comment: I've voted General Reference, but maybe I should have said Not Constructive. There's no "rule of grammar" in play here, and some people do insert a comma. Most don't, as OP should know if he's ever received a letter or email starting with *"Hello Brad[,]"*. People *very* rarely put a comma between the greeting and the addressee's name in that context.

Comment: I voted off topic. It's not general reference; there is no general reference on comma usage, and it's not about English grammar and usage because it's about punctuation. It's hard to choose sometimes.

Comment: +1 I can't see that it's off-topic. English grammar includes punctuation; there's a reason why we have the punctuation tags.  It's also not really gen ref, for the reason Prof. Lawler pointed out.  Not Constructive is the closest bet, I'd say; but I can't bring myself to vote to close this one.  I was almost about to say *there **has** to be a duplicate of this somewhere*, but I would like to sound rather less trigger-happy.

Comment: I searched for duplicates before I posted this. And sure, people don't put the comma in a salutation but shouldn't they? If the answer is "no" that is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Daniel I agree with you, but I do note vote up because that does not seem to be the best question that I have never seen.

Comment: I think asking about a computer program title is off-topic.  If you were to reword the question to ask about the punctuation of salutations in general (and misuse thereof), then you're asking about a more general English problem and the question would be more appropriate here.

Comment: @John Lawler: I find I increasingly side with you on the matter of punctuation. As you're wont to say, *language* is essentially a *spoken* phenomenon - punctuation is bordering on irrelevant. I realise quite a few people here either want to ask or answer issues of orthography - but most of the time, I wish they wouldn't.

Comment: I was trying to think of how the comma is important here like it would be in these sentences: "John read the book" and "John, read the book". Those are two very different things and I wasn't sure if the same logic would apply here.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Despite it not being a linguistic phenomenon, punctuation is considered well with the scope of ELU (see the FAQ).

Comment: @Mitch: I did say I realise that. I just get fed up with what so often ends up being pointless discussion on matters of choice, and quoting of style guides.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: punctuation is on-topic and is well represented here. See the FAQ. (I'm not making any statement otherwise about the quality of this question)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: OK. Yeah lots of things are matters of choice, punctuation or otherwise.

Comment: @Carlo_R. How can you vote on questions you've never seen?  Anyhow, everyone who only voted on the best post they ever saw would only vote once.

Comment: If you ignore the fact that the question contains a reference to programming (which is, I suspect, the reason for all the upvotes), how is this question different from [Where should the comma be placed in the salutation of a letter?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/where-should-the-comma-be-placed-in-the-salutation-of-a-letter)

Comment: @Danielδ: Sorry, English grammar does **not** include [punctuation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf). English punctuation is not standard; it has nothing to do with English grammar; and there are no grammatical rules that govern it. There is no punctuation in language, only in orthography.

Comment: Re the close. The question is decidedly __not__ off-topic, but it is a dupe of the question Cameron cited.

Comment: @JohnLawler I take your point; I should have said that the domain of English Language and Usage includes, or at least overlaps, the domain of orthography.  As Mitch said, punctuation is on-topic and as such, well represented in this site. The [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) says: *Questions on the following topics are welcomed here: [...] Spelling and punctuation*

Comment: That's true, but unfortunate. I agree with FF above: I'm afraid that questions about punctuation are rarely answered consistently and well here, no matter how definitively.

Comment: Well, I've certainly learned my lesson here...I was not expecting such a harsh reaction to, what I thought was, a simple curiosity. Especially since i was using established tags which seemed to fit my question.

Comment: Question is on-topic as per FAQ entry regarding punctutation, is reasonably constructive, is a real question, is not too localized, and is not clearly ["basic and trivial"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/). No duplicates have been suggested; question accordingly reopened.

Comment: @Brad I sympathize with you; IMO we (I included) have increasingly become too quick to close and find fault with questions.  Please realize that there has been a bunch of real garbage asked on this site of late, and that even some of the veteran users have become paranoid and/or apathetic about question quality here.  Now watch as I get whipped off my feet for saying that...  but I hope you can understand, and that your experience hasn't been too negative.

Comment: @waiwai933: sadly needs to be closed because it's a dupe.

Comment: @Danielδ Thanks. I understand this stuff coming to a head somewhere...it just happens to be my question. This certainly has not given me a negative impression or anything, that's just the way it is.

Comment: And remember, since it looks like it really is a duplicate, that closing as a duplicate (especially an obscure and non-obvious one) is the most honorable of the close reasons :)

Comment: @Cameron: _How is this question different from 'Where should the comma be placed in the salutation of a letter?'_ I'll say where I see the difference; the FAQ says to ask practical questions based on actual problems that you face. If I'm writing a business letter, I don't want to appear illiterate – I need to know where that comma goes. If I'm making sure I can compile a program and spit output onto the screen, it matters little whether or not I've punctuated my output correctly. Grammatically, there may be very little difference, but I see a wide gulf in the practicality of the two questions.

Comment: Since the first thing that a "Hello World" program does is terminates, it might be better to call it a "Goodbye, cruel world." program.

Comment: The "correct" presentation of the words is exactly that used by Kernighan and Ritchie in the very first demo program written in the C programming language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst according to my memory inserting the comma is technically correct, it is now rarely seen in everyday communications. I favour ***Hello World***, therefore.

Answer (score 5):

Conventional orthography demands:

> Hello, world!

but, given the context, it doesn't really matter what you type.  In my experience, the following is common:

> Hello world

Since a "Hello world" program terminates immediately after printing its message, I personally prefer:

> Goodbye, world.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, Wikipedia calls it the [**"Hello world" program**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program), but indicates there should be a comma in the output:

> A "Hello world" program is a computer program that outputs "Hello, world" on a display device.

[Other sources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) make this two-word phrase an exclamation:

> **Lesson: A Closer Look at the "Hello World!" Application**
>
> Now that you've seen the "Hello World!" application (and perhaps even compiled and run it), you might be wondering how it works. Here again is its code:
>
> ```
> class HelloWorldApp {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
>     }
> }
> ```

[Other times](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Programming/Hello_world), both the comma *and* the exclamation point are used:

> *Hello, world!* programs make the text "Hello, world!" appear on a computer screen.

Incidentally, [this website](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Programming/Hello_world) lists several *Hello world* programs, most of which use both the comma and the exclamation point, although there are a few exceptions, like this one:

> ```
> xhello db 'Hello world !!!$'
> ```

Ultimately, though, in this context, it matters very little what's between the quotation marks, so long as the program runs.

Comment: +1 for actually answering and addressing the concerns of the initial reaction to remove the question. This is what I was looking for.