# Is the correct format "Good morning, John" or "Good morning John"?

Tags: punctuation, sentence, commas

Which of these is in the correct format?

> Good morning, John.

Or

> Good morning John.

Comment: Even though the specific question is not the same, the answers to the following question are very relevant: [Where should the comma be placed in the salutation of a letter?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/where-should-the-comma-be-placed-in-the-salutation-of-a-letter) There are also a bunch of [similar questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1025?lq=1) linked to that one.

Comment: A "good morning John"　(no comma)  is a well-behaved, morning customer of a prostitute's services

Comment: I really wish this question had not been closed. I really needed this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Nouns of address -- those naming the person or thing to which the sentence is addressed -- should always be set off from the rest of the sentence by commas.  This applies whether they appear at the beginning of the sentence,

> English sufferer, pay attention!

in the middle,

> You, English sufferer, should make a note of this.

or at the end.

> Have you got it, English sufferer?

This is not an arbitrary rule.  Nouns of address need to be separated because they are grammatically independent of the rest of the sentence.  Leaving out the commas can completely change the meaning.  Consider:

> Good God!

(an exclamation of shock)

*vs*.

> Good, God!

(a religious acclamation).

Or consider the life-saving importance of the comma in

> Let's eat, Grandma!

Comment: I assume then that the correct punctuation in the questioner's case would be, "Good morning, John."